# Format date string in carbon in laravel5?

Tags: php, date, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I want to convert `$date='01-07-2010'` in to `2010-07-01`

My following code is not wokring,

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

It throws error,

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 414: Trailing data
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your date format is `d-m-Y` then

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

won't work, because you're not specifying the correct format; you need

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date);
```

---

The format that you specify as the date-format for your value must match the actual format of the date string that you want to convert to a Carbon object